# What is equivalent to .createAlias in hibernate 5+ using entity manager

Tags: hibernate, jpa, annotations

I have two entities Person and Account with One to One relationships.
In my old hibernate i have the following method to filter person.

```
public List filterByPersonalInfo(String personal_info) throws Exception{
    List values = null;
    Session session = getSession();
    Criteria criteria = getHBCriteria(session, personal_info);

    criteria.addOrder(Order.desc("person_id"));
    values = criteria.list();
    return values;
}

private Criteria getHBCriteria(Session session, String personal_info) throws       Exception {

Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(Person.class).createAlias("account", "acc")
            .add(
                    Restrictions.disjunction()

                    .add(Restrictions.ilike("first_name", personal_info, MatchMode.ANYWHERE))
                    .add(Restrictions.ilike("middle_name", personal_info, MatchMode.ANYWHERE))
                    .add(Restrictions.ilike("last_name", personal_info, MatchMode.ANYWHERE))
                    .add(Restrictions.ilike("cnic", personal_info, MatchMode.ANYWHERE))
                    .add(Restrictions.ilike("gender", personal_info, MatchMode.START))
                    .add(Restrictions.ilike("zipcode", personal_info, MatchMode.ANYWHERE))
                    .add(Restrictions.ilike("address1", personal_info, MatchMode.ANYWHERE))
                    .add(Restrictions.ilike("address2", personal_info, MatchMode.ANYWHERE))
                    .add(Restrictions.ilike("phone_no", personal_info, MatchMode.ANYWHERE))

                    .add(Restrictions.ilike("acc.username", personal_info, MatchMode.ANYWHERE))
                    .add(Restrictions.ilike("acc.email", personal_info, MatchMode.ANYWHERE))
           );

    return criteria;
}
```

Now i want to switch to Hibernate 5 or above (using jpa annotations). I need equivalent to the above, using entity manager.
What i did so far is as below.

```
public List<Person> filterByPersonalInfo(String personal_info) throws Exception{
    List<Person> list = null;

      EntityManager em = HibernateUtil.getEntityManager();
      CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
      CriteriaQuery<Person> cq = cb.createQuery(Person.class);
      Root<Person> root = cq.from(Person.class);
      EntityType<Person> type = em.getMetamodel().entity(Person.class);

    // Where
      cq.where(
            cb.or(
            cb.like(root.get(type.getDeclaredSingularAttribute("first_name", String.class)), "%" + personal_info + "%"),
            cb.like(root.get(type.getDeclaredSingularAttribute("middle_name", String.class)), "%" + personal_info + "%"),
            cb.like(root.get(type.getDeclaredSingularAttribute("last_name", String.class)), "%" + personal_info + "%"),
            cb.like(root.get(type.getDeclaredSingularAttribute("cnic", String.class)), "%" + personal_info + "%"),
            cb.like(root.get(type.getDeclaredSingularAttribute("gender", String.class)), "%" + personal_info + "%"),
            cb.like(root.get(type.getDeclaredSingularAttribute("zipcode", String.class)), "%" + personal_info + "%"),
            cb.like(root.get(type.getDeclaredSingularAttribute("address1", String.class)), "%" + personal_info + "%"),
            cb.like(root.get(type.getDeclaredSingularAttribute("address2", String.class)), "%" + personal_info + "%"),
            cb.like(root.get(type.getDeclaredSingularAttribute("phone_no", String.class)), "%" + personal_info + "%")
            )
    );

    // Order By
    cq.orderBy(cb.desc(root.get("person_id")));

    list = em.createQuery(cq).getResultList();
    return list;
}
```

I don't know how to filter through Account's attributes i.e username and email.

Thanks.

Comment: What does createAlias() do? What does its javadoc say? It says "Join an association, assigning an alias to the joined association.". How could you create a join and navigate through a joined association, from the Root<Person> you have? https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/criteria/Root.html

Comment: You'd better generate the entity metamodel classes to use the criteria API. That's what makes it safe and refactorable. But for a static query, that doesn't need to be generated from criteria, I would just use JPQL.